# Access Violation Issues

Tags: access-violation

I am still fairly unfamiliar with this stuff.  I am trying to write a simple parser for my senior project.  I have it working most of the time, but as I get it to parse longer and longer files it starts giving me an access violation error.  Here is an example of what I am parsing (APRS packet in a .txt file)

```
> # 1342977832 Sun Jul 22 11:23:51  2012 WB1SAR-11>APT3A2,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1:/172347h4014.07N/11004.38WO227/015/A=047664/HARBOR
```

After doing some research it seems obvious that the problem is in the for loops with the pointers, but I don't know what exactly to do about it.  Thanks for your help.
    The code is:
        int GetLat(char* parse_test, char* line_string)
    {
        int B_GPS_lat_deg = 0;
        float B_GPS_lat_min = 0;

```
    parse_test = strstr(line_string,"h"); //the latitude starts after the time.  time ends with "h".  
    char deg_buffer[2]; // buffer to use with atof() which converts an array to a float
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)// skip the "h" and load the first 2 characters after that into buffer
    {
        parse_test++;
        deg_buffer[k] = *parse_test;
    }

    B_GPS_lat_deg = atof(deg_buffer);// convert to float     

    char min_buffer[5];  // buffer for the minutes
    for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++) // copies the minutes from the parse_test to the buffer
    {
        parse_test++;
        min_buffer[k] = *parse_test;
    }  
    B_GPS_lat_min = atof(min_buffer); //convert to float

    gps_ball_lat = B_GPS_lat_deg+(B_GPS_lat_min/60); //convert from ddmm.mm to decimal degrees dd.dddd
    cout << gps_ball_lat << "\n";

    return(0);
```

}

Comment: Are you doing this line by line? The first line doesn't have an "h". Would that break your code?

Comment: The chars immediately after "h" are "4014.07". That's 2 chars ("40") for the first loop and you should use 5 chars ("14.07") for the second loop but you use 4 chars instead. Or am I misreading it?

Comment: That is right, I have changed it and still have the same problem.

Comment: I think you need a null character at the end of each string you pass to ``atof()``. Try declaring the buffers with 3 and 6 chars respectively and add a ``'\0''`` to the last char before calling ``atof()``

Comment: I think I just tried this, but to verify I am indexing my arrays properly here is an example.  deg_buffer is a 3 char array.  to make the last value of that array NULL I would use this:         deg_buffer[2] = '\0';

Comment: That's what I would do. Did you do it for min_buffer too?

Comment: Please update the code in the question. Can you tell which line it's breaking on? Try commenting out the code that handles minutes and see if it still errors. That should narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Acces violations occurs when you try to acces memory that is not given to your program. Check that you are not accesing array indexes lower than 0 and bigger than array length.

For example here:

```
parse_test++; //<---- Are you sure that parse_test has enough chars?
deg_buffer[k] = *parse_test;
```

you asume that parste_test has more or equal than k elements.

Comment: I believe there should be plenty of extra characters in it.  Here is what my debugger says parse_test is holding:
    parse_test = 0x28fcfa "008.92N/11007.59WO000/000/A=005383/SBATS-3!wxS!"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that strstr() can return a NULL and was.  I didn't check for this and this caused the issue.  Here is how I fixed it for my code.  I added the "if" statement.

`parse_test = strstr(line_string,"h"); //the latitude starts after the time.  time ends with "h".

        if(parse_test == NULL) // if it can't find an "h" skip this line and continue parsing the file
            continue;
        char deg_buffer[3]; // buffer to use with atof() which converts an array to a float`

Thanks to all for your help, even if it didn't fix that problem I am sure that it cleaned my code up and prevented others!!!!